# Can't establish connection with the OVH's SMTP

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

```
from smtplib import SMTP
SMTP("SSL0.OVH.NET", 465)
```

SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

Hum, this error message is frustrating, I have no clues of what I can do !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from smtplib import SMTP
SMTP("SSL0.OVH.NET", 587)
```

I don't know why but this work.
OVH should be 993 to send to and 465 to send from but it works better with 587 which should work to send from gmail.